# Converting NSString to keyCode+modifiers for AXUIElementPostKeyboardEvent

Tags: cocoa, unicode, nsstring, accessibility

Edit: Turns out, I was misled during my initial explorations of the accessibility APIs. Once I found the secure text field in the AX hierarchy, I was easily able to set the value. Not sure what to do with this question beyond that, but I wanted to update this for future searchers.

I'm working on some code that will post keyboard events to targeted applications using the Accessibility APIs. So far, I have been able to write a trivial app that allows me to type in a string value and then post keyboard events with those key codes to the targeted application. In reality, the strings would be read from another location.

What I have not yet been able to figure out is how to ascertain whether and which modifier keys should also be posted. For instance, when I type `Hello, world!` into my test application, the input is sent to the other application as `hello, world1` because I am not yet including the modifier keys to create the upper case H and the exclamation point. This is made doubly complicated by multi-keystroke characters like `é` or `ü`. Sending `é` sends  a raw `e` with no accent for example.

Is there a simple method I am overlooking for discerning the modifiers to combine with a keycode for creating a particular NSString or unichar? If not, does anyone have a suggestion of how to proceed? So far, the best I have come up with is calling `UCKeyTranslate` with all possible modifier combinations until I find one that matches the `unichar` I get using `-[NSString characterAtIndex:]` I'm not sure this is scalable or reliable, though, given the multi-keystroke nature of some characters as noted above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't help. But just in case: Is it really necessary to send keyboard events? Because that is going to get really difficult if you need to support, say, Kotoeri.

It's a simple matter to override insertText: and doCommandBySelector: and send the results of the key sequence, rather than the individual keystrokes.

Comment: No, I don't think this will work for my case because sometimes I will need to enter text into password fields and as far as I can tell, AXUIElements representing password fields do not allow you to directly set the value using the usual accessibility value setting calls. (I wish they did!)

Comment: The other problem with Ross's approach is that eventually I want to read the string from a file and send that value to the other application.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a example which does the [trick](http://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder/source/browse/trunk/Source/SRKeyCodeTransformer.m) but it's incomplete:It will not be a general solution in any case ...how can this handle multiple keyboard layouts ?

There is an cgquartz obsolete function to do so: [CGPostKeyboardEvent](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPostKeyboardEvent) (not sure it's possible to pass only the char?) may be can still be used (marked undocumented with some side effect to but .. ).

EDIT: UCKeyTranslate as a way to build a dictionary. Interesting but how the OS do this? A better answer should be hidden somewhere !